MiKTeX Console fails to start after update of package miktex-qt5-bin-x64
I am having trouble with the installation of MikTeX.
Specifications: I am using Windows 11 (Version 22H2 (Build 22621.3527)).
The problem is this:
Yesterday I installed MikTeX according to (the instructions given on the MiKTeX homepage) (I did install it into the default directory) using the basic installer. However, when running an update via the MikTeX Console I got a notification that the package miktex-qt5-bin-x64
was damaged and needed to be repaired, so I attempted to update it using the console. But upon my attempt to restart MiKTeX Console I got the error message
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized.   
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. 
Available platform plugins are: windows. 

Of course the issue here is that it is not really possible to uninstall MiKTeX when the console cannot be launched. So my question is: What is a possible way to fix the installation? Alternatively, what is the best way to uninstall MiKTeX in this situation?

run on a command line miktex packages update, then the console will start again. Check if they are updates and install them. Perhaps you will afterwards have to run miktex packages update again. See also my comments here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1486

Had the same problem. Running miktex packages update in the command prompt as recommended by Ulrike Fischer solved the problem.

If miktex packages update didn't work for you (like it was in my case, moreover, I even was unable to uninstall MikTeX because of the same error) then try  miktex --admin packages update. Probably, all users who use MikTeX administrative mode should use this option.

Try running the software in Admin mode (in the Overview panel, click on "Switch to MiKTeX administrator mode") before checking for updates.
